# Not able to comment on my own question without reputation

Tags: support, comments

I am not able to comment on my own question. So the flow goes like

1) Posted a question

2) Someone posted a comment to my question asking for some more details or some suggestions.

3) I am not able to reply to them because I don't have 15 reputation.

I think it will be good to remove this constraint atleast for the my own posts. No?

Link to the question [Java BufferedReader vs Separate Producer consumer thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157171/java-bufferedreader-vs-separate-producer-consumer-thread/157207#157207)

Comment: You are already supposed to be able to do this. The rep is only for commenting *elsewhere*.

Comment: Are you sure you are typing more than 15 characters!

Comment: [how-do-comments-work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) and [cant-comment-on-other-posts-able-to-comment-on-own](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32352/cant-comment-on-other-posts-able-to-comment-on-own?rq=1)

Comment: Nope, I just posted a question in programmers.stackexchange, and with a reputation 1 I don't see add comment option. Just now... Once I get 6 reputation, I got the add comment option. Actually the same goes for posting pictures in the question rite?

Comment: [whats the justification for the commenting reputation requirement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66141/176291)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I saw.

Comment: @MohanKumar: Yet you commented here on your own question, and you only have 1 rep on MSO. Clearly the system is working for you despite your lack of rep.

Comment: Yes I did. Surprisingly I can't that time.

Comment: Moving this to programmers meta, as it's a specific issue on *that* site.  Also, I suggest you post a link to the question you can't post a comment on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, the issue appears resolved:

1. you were able to comment on the question: [Added details in the question...](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157171/java-bufferedreader-vs-separate-producer-consumer-thread/157207#comment299775_157171)
2. you were able to comment on the answer to your question: [As you say, It depends on the IO wait...](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157171/java-bufferedreader-vs-separate-producer-consumer-thread/157207#comment299796_157207)

<sub>For the sake of completeness, adding also a reference to question timeline:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/157171/timeline

Sudden breakthrough in ability to comment could possibly be triggered by question upvote

but I wouldn't bet on that given that [privileges page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges) doesn't show any statement about this.</sub>